# Переменная для каждого пользователя в боте вк

Tags: python

Если я добавляю переменную, которая считает количество отправленных сообщений, то она считает количество отправленных сообщений всех пользователей. А могу ли я считать количество сообщений, отправленных конкретно одним пользователем?

Answer (score 1):

У каждого пользователя в вк есть свой id его можно получить после того как пользователь отправил что-нибудь боту.

### **Решение**

Создаем бд, в бд создаем таблицу users_messages а, в таблице создаем 2 столбика id и messages, когда пользователь пишет боту, в коде проверяется если уже есть id этого пользователя то в столбце messages где id равно id этого пользователя прибавляется 1 но, если id этого пользователя нет то просто в столбик id  добавляется id  этого пользователя и в messages +1

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать БД для этого.
Но если не хотите, то можно создать словарь, где ключами будут являться идентификаторы пользователей, а данными количество их сообщений. Если пользователь новый, то надо генерировать исключение через оболочку `try ... except` и добавлять новую пару ключ-значение.

Comment: Не обязательно генерировать исключение через `try ... except` Можно через `dict.get(key, 0)` - при отсутствии такого ключа (в данном случае ID пользователя), будет создана пара `ID: 0`

Comment: Согласен, но генерируя исключение можно сделать оповещение о новом юзере, например